# How can I undo "hide all from <web site>"? (NOT hide all from person, page, group, or app)

Tags: facebook

I used this option to hide all Facebook posts that link to a specific external web site:
[image: Facebook post context menu with options "Hide post", "Unfollow David", "Hide all from Eventbrite" (highlighted), "Report post", "Save link", and "Turn on notifications"]

How can I undo this?

Note that I hid all content from an external web site — not from a Facebook person, page, group, or app — so the [News Feed Preferences](https://www.facebook.com/help/371675846332829) dialog is *not* applicable here.

Comment: Even if it was a person/page, I can't find any way to undo it! Needs feed prefs only lets you "reconnect" with friends or pages you "unfollowed" (see http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/83065/how-do-i-undo-hide-all-from-page-non-friend-person-in-facebook)